# vector file is used by two mapsets at a time in grass gis

Tags: grass-gis, vector

i want to study about vector processing.if a vector file is used by two mapsets at a time, which one will  be saved first and why.if a team want to work on the same set of shape files, what is the procedure. will it be saved in dbf format?

Answer (score 1):

> if a vector file is used by two mapsets at a time, which one will be saved first and why.

- You can *read* GRASS GIS vector maps from different mapsets. IF your
  operating system permits (most do it), also concurrently.
- You can *write* to a GRASS GIS vector map only in the current mapset.
- You can have only one user being active in a mapset.

See also: http://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/vectorlib.html

> if a team want to work on the same set of shape files, what is the procedure.

Do you mean to read or to write?

> will it be saved in dbf format?

Depends:

- if you work with GRASS GIS 6, then DBF is the default attribute table format
- if you work with GRASS GIS 7, then SQLite is the default attribute table format

However, you can always define that differently with db.connect. And furthermore export the table to a different format (e.g. PostGIS).

See also: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Category:Vector

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer if was is helpful.